# Multiple Columns Concatenation

Tags: oracle

I would like to concatenate multiple columns but I want to set conditions to exclude some strings and not to include if column value is dash(-) only.

```
Data:
D1      D2      D3      D4
AAA-BBB BBB-CCC CCC_DDD DDD-AAA
CCC-AAA AAA-BBB BBB-CCC -

Desired output:
Result
AAA-BBB-CCC_DDD-AAA
CCC-AAA-BBB-CCC
```

Comment: You need to replace `’` and `‘` with `'` otherwise you will get syntax errors.

Comment: How is the idea to use STRING_SPLIT and the concatenate?

Comment: @Sujay: You suggestion is to move the database from Oracle to SQL Server in order to use their `STRING_SPLIT` function? And how would that remove the duplicate substrings?

Comment: All your strings start with the substring that the previous string ended with, and you want that part de-duplicated. What result would you want for 'AAA-BBB' | 'CCC-DDD' | '-'  | '-'? What result for 'AAA' | 'AAA-BBB' | '-'  | '-'?  And what result for 'AAA-BBB' | '-' | '-'  | 'BBB-CCC'?

Comment: The underline seems to count as much as a delimter as the minus. But in the result you want the underline in 'AAA-BBB-CCC_DDD-AAA' or would 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-AAA' be just as good? Are there other delimiters like a comma, a semicolon, ...?

Comment: What is the expected output if your strings are `'AAA-BBB', '-', '-', 'BBB-CCC'`? Or `'AAA-AAA', 'AAA-AAA', 'AAA-AAA', 'AAA-AAA'`?

Comment: @MT0 it should be AAA-BBB-CCC every value in the column will not be repeated I mean it will not be like this AAA-AAA or BBB-BBB or CCC-CCC, etc.

Comment: The rule is not clear to me. Would 'AAA-BBB', 'BB-CC', 'C-D', 'DD-EE' become 'AAA-BBB-CC-DD-EE' then?

Comment: What I want is that to concatenate first all the columns except for those have dash(-) only in it. So the final result should be Row1 AAA-BBB-CCC_DDD-AAA
Row2 CCC-AAA-BBB-CCC eliminated for those 2nd occurrence next to each other.

Comment: In Oracle, You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` instead of `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: @Sujay Your comment of "you can use `<insert_function>`" is not constructive because it does not tell the OP **how** that function would be valuable to them. If you have a solution to the problem then create an answer that describes the solution.

Comment: Please edit your request and clarify all the open questions. What exactly are the rules to detect duplicates? I understand that in 'AAA-BBB' followed by 'BBB-CCC' you see 'BBB' as a duplicate because it is separated by a dash. In your sample data, though, you also have 'CCC_DDD' which doesn't contain a dash, but still you consider CCC and DDD separate tokens you want to de-duplicate. Would you do the same with 'CCC#DDD' and with 'CCCXDDD' and with 'CCCDDD'?

Comment: We don't even know your real data. In your sample it is very simple; it is always three letters a dash and three letters. But is there always a dash in your real data? Oh, well, no, it isn't, it can be an underline at least. So, edit your request. Tell us what makes you consider a part of a string removable. Would 'AAA-BB', 'BCD-EFG' become 'AAA-B-CD-EFG' maybe, because the first string ends on B and the second starts with it? Clarify in your request.

Comment: As far as I see, the question is not clear in this case. Try to put it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to concatenate all the strings with `-` delimiters and then use two passes of a regular expression looking for the preceding delimiter then a duplicated term with a `-` between and then a following delimiter. You need to use the surrounding delimiters to ensure that you match full terms and you need two passes as the delimiter in the middle of each value needs to be matched for both the left and right of each term and Oracle does not support zero-width look-ahead in regular expressions so you cannot match duplicates in both left and right in the pass.

```sql
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               '-' || D1 || '-' || D2 || '-' || d3 || '-' || D4 || '-',
               '-{2,}',
               '-'
             ),
             '([-_])([^-_]+)-\2([-_])',
             '\1\2\3'
           ),
           '([-_])([^-_]+)-\2([-_])',
           '\1\2\3'
         )
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (D1, D2, D3, D4) AS
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', 'BBB-CCC', 'CCC_DDD', 'DDD-AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC-AAA', 'AAA-BBB', 'BBB-CCC', '-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', '-', '-', 'BBB-CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EEE-FFF', 'GGG-HHH' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| AAA-BBB-CCC_DDD-AAA |
| CCC-AAA-BBB-CCC |
| AAA-BBB-CCC |
| AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH |

---

If the terms in your strings are always exactly 3 characters long then you can simplify it to:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             D1 || '-' || D2 || '-' || d3 || '-' || D4,
             '-{2,}',
             '-'
           ),
           '([^-_]{3})-\1',
           '\1'
         )
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs the same.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bUeylQYG)

Comment: This is way simpler and better for me. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, always 3 chars only.

Comment: @Noel 5 columns works for me [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S7oc8cXu)

Answer (score 0):

Split the each of the 4 columns into left and right parts (giving 8 columns), and then `UNPIVOT` those 8 columns into 8 rows (or less if there were any `-` values) and compare the value for each row with the value of the previous row and eliminate any neighbouring duplicates and then re-aggregate the rows.

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(val, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY idx) AS result
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         CASE
         WHEN LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY idx) = val
         THEN NULL
         ELSE val
         END AS val,
         idx
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS id,
           CASE WHEN d1 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d1, 1, 3) END AS d1_1, 
           CASE WHEN d1 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d1, 5, 3) END AS d1_2,
           CASE WHEN d2 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d2, 1, 3) END AS d2_1,
           CASE WHEN d2 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d2, 5, 3) END AS d2_2,
           CASE WHEN d3 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d3, 1, 3) END AS d3_1,
           CASE WHEN d3 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d3, 5, 3) END AS d3_2,
           CASE WHEN d4 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d4, 1, 3) END AS d4_1,
           CASE WHEN d4 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d4, 5, 3) END AS d4_2
    FROM   table_name
  )
  UNPIVOT (
    val FOR idx IN (
       d1_1 AS 1,
       d1_2 AS 2,
       d2_1 AS 3,
       d2_2 AS 4,
       d3_1 AS 5,
       d3_2 AS 6,
       d4_1 AS 7,
       d4_2 AS 8
    )
  )
)
WHERE  val IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (D1, D2, D3, D4) AS
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', 'BBB-CCC', 'CCC_DDD', 'DDD-AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC-AAA', 'AAA-BBB', 'BBB-CCC', '-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', '-', '-', 'BBB-CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-AAA', 'AAA-AAA', 'AAA-AAA', 'AAA-AAA' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-AAA |
| CCC-AAA-BBB-CCC |
| AAA-BBB-CCC |
| AAA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c_OljptQ)

---

If you want to do it without splitting and aggregating then you can split into columns and then use multiple in-line views with `CASE` expressions to handle merging the strings under the different cases:

```sql
WITH split_data (d1_1, d1_2, d2_1, d2_2, d3_1, d3_2, d4_1, d4_2) AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN d1 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d1, 1, 3) END AS d1_1, 
           CASE WHEN d1 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d1, 5, 3) END AS d1_2,
           CASE WHEN d2 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d2, 1, 3) END AS d2_1,
           CASE WHEN d2 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d2, 5, 3) END AS d2_2,
           CASE WHEN d3 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d3, 1, 3) END AS d3_1,
           CASE WHEN d3 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d3, 5, 3) END AS d3_2,
           CASE WHEN d4 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d4, 1, 3) END AS d4_1,
           CASE WHEN d4 = '-' THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR(d4, 5, 3) END AS d4_2
    FROM   table_name
),
merge_level_1 (d1_1, d12, d2_2, d3_1, d34, d4_2) AS (
  SELECT d1_1,
         CASE
         WHEN d1_2 != d2_1
         THEN d1_2 || '-' || d2_1
         ELSE COALESCE(d1_2, d2_1)
         END,
         d2_2,
         d3_1,
         CASE
         WHEN d3_2 != d4_1
         THEN d3_2 || '-' || d4_1
         ELSE COALESCE(d3_2, d4_1)
         END,
         d4_2
  FROM   split_data
),
merge_level_2 (d1_1, d1234, d4_2) AS (
  SELECT d1_1,
         CASE
         WHEN d2_2 = d3_1
         THEN d12 || '-' || d2_2 || '-' || d34
         WHEN d2_2 != d3_1
         THEN d12 || '-' || d2_2 || '-' || d3_1 || '-' || d34
         WHEN d12 = d34
         THEN d12
         ELSE d12 || '-' || d34
         END,
         d4_2
  FROM   merge_level_1
)
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM d1_1 || '-' || d1234 || '-' || d4_2) AS result
FROM   merge_level_2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (D1, D2, D3, D4) AS
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', 'BBB-CCC', 'CCC_DDD', 'DDD-AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC-AAA', 'AAA-BBB', 'BBB-CCC', '-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', '-', '-', 'BBB-CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA-BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EEE-FFF', 'GGG-HHH' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-AAA |
| CCC-AAA-BBB-CCC |
| AAA-BBB-CCC |
| AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xr_aD07t)

Comment: This is a bit complicated, is there anyway to replace or remove the identical string next to each other after concatenation? Example: Concatenated: AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC-CCC_DDD-DDD-AAA remove the second -BBB and and second -CCC second -DDD?

Comment: @Noel Yes... but the problem was concatenating `'AAA-BBB', '-', '-', 'BBB-CCC'` where you want to merge `D1` and `D4` and ignore `D2` and `D3`.

Comment: There should be two rows only. So the final result should be Row1 AAA-BBB-CCC_DDD-AAA
Row2 CCC-AAA-BBB-CCC the rest  of the columns have dash(-) only in it should be disregarded or not included during concatenation.

Comment: @Noel Updated with a second version that does not `PIVOT` and re-aggregate.

Comment: Hi MT0, it seems so complicated, I have small idea in my mind what if I will concatenate it first this way AAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-AAA then use REGEXP_SUBSTR to capture the first 3 chars if there’s 6 chars between dashes but never include the last dashes if there’s any.